Не запускается докер контейнер с базой данных
У меня проект на Джанго, где я использую PostgreSQL. Я создал базу данных и перенес данные, после чего монтировал ее в Docker. Какое-то время все запускалось, однако спустя 2-3 минуты контейнер с PostgreSQL вылетал. Сейчас вообще не запускается. В логах пишет следующее:
2024-05-12 00:05:15 chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
2024-05-12 00:05:16 chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
2024-05-12 00:05:16 
2024-05-12 00:05:16 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2024-05-12 00:05:16 
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.066 MSK [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.066 MSK [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.066 MSK [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.068 MSK [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.073 MSK [29] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-05-11 23:29:20 MSK
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.538 MSK [29] LOG:  invalid resource manager ID in checkpoint record
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.538 MSK [29] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.538 MSK [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 29) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.538 MSK [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2024-05-12 00:05:16 2024-05-12 00:05:16.538 MSK [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
 

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8' 
  
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./movies_admin:/movies_admin"
    env_file:
      - "movies_admin/config/.env"
    depends_on:
      - database
      - elasticsearch
  
  database:

    image: postgres:16

    environment:
    
      - DB_NAME=movies_database
      - DB_USER=app
      - DB_PASSWORD=123qwe
    
    volumes:
      - /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@16:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
  

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - "./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
      - "./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/admin:/etc/nginx/movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/admin"
      - "./movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/rest_framework:/etc/nginx/movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/rest_framework"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django
  
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.13.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms200m -Xmx200m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'movies_database',
        'USER': 'app',
        'PASSWORD': '123qwe',
        'HOST': 'database',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=public,content'
        }
    }
} 


Пробовал восстановить базу из бакапа? Ну или заново ее создать?

Нет, не пробовал. А как создание базы данных снова решит проблему?

@Allito А если удалить все файлы внутри контейнера и монтировать заново, имеет смысл?

Ну судя по ошибке - postgres не может открыть базу и в итоге выдает ошибку "could not locate a valid checkpoint record". Подозрения падают на целостность базы.
